# Input number not showing in output for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have been a code in which you have to put in a number and the program in python will keep multiplying that number from the letter a to z.
The code is shown below, everthing works except for the fact that it start printing with input * 2 and not with input.

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(26):
    uitvoer= chr(ord('a')+i)
    n *=2
    n1 = str(n)
    print (f'{uitvoer} {n1[::-1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Now check your output.

```
n = int(input())
print ("input ",n)
for i in range(26):
    uitvoer= chr(ord('a')+i)
    n1 = str(n)
    print (f'{uitvoer} {n1[::-1]}')
    n *=2
```

Comment: So my original output looks like this with input as 2, but i want it to start with 2 and not 4

a 4    
b 8    
c 61   
d 23
e 46
f 821
g 652
h 215
i 4201
j 8402
k 6904
l 2918
m 48361
n 86723
o 63556
p 270131
q 441262
r 882425
s 6758401
t 2517902
u 4034914
v 8068838
w 61277761
x 23445533
y 46880176
z 827712431

Comment: now try the above code again.
my results =>a 2
b 4
c 8
d 61
e 23
f 46
g 821
h 652
i 215
j 4201
k 8402
l 6904
m 2918
n 48361
o 86723
p 63556
q 270131
r 441262
s 882425
t 6758401
u 2517902
v 4034914
w 8068838
x 61277761
y 23445533
z 46880176